# Non-technical person facing technical issues with .Net framework

Tags: .net-framework, asp.net, .net-3.5, .net-4.0

Like the title says I have near to no clue as to what is going on with the .net framework programs. I tried installing programs like discord onto my laptop only to experience a error saying "net framework is not installed" so I went and got a legit copy of .net framework 4.7 from Microsoft. It then told me I already had so-called .net framework, but all my programs are having a fit over finding .net framework 4.7. According to my laptop I have all net frameworks from 3.5 up, but I went to uninstall programs and the turn on/off windows features to which I have:
- .NET Environment
- .NET Extensibility 3.5
- .NET Extensibility 4.8
- ASP.NET 4.8
But nothing else I had seen in Youtube Videos. I hope I've given enough information and I'd be more than happy to support with more information on this .net framework frenzy.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the 'delightful' aspects of how Microsoft distributes its shared libraries...

You don't need the delevoper-level .NET installations, but you do need the end-user versions, 'Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable '

However, there's no simple way, at consumer-level, to know precisely which version any given app is built against, so you end up having to go down this list - [Microsoft Support: The latest supported Visual C++ downloads](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads) - in reverse date order & keep installing them one at a time until you find the right one.

Complaints to Microsoft ;)

There is a more comprehensive list of all the historic versions at [iTechtics - Download Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable (All Versions)](https://www.itechtics.com/microsoft-visual-c-redistributable-versions-direct-download-links/) but you should be OK just using the Microsoft links.