# .Net Framework 4.7.2 does not seem to “include” frameworks below 4.6.2

Tags: windows-10, crash, .net-framework, file-corruption

Whenever I boot my PC, my computer responds with dialogue boxes.

[Desktop screen after around 30 seconds, 4.5 crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hfcp4.png)

Now, this happened since after updating my PC. (Around late 2019, November 2019 update) I updated my win10 after a long while and restarted it. And it broke some applications. And I can not run some applications any more, some of which I need to continue programming.

I uninstalled 4.8 (the .NET FW installed when things started breaking) and ran multiple .Net FW runtime installers on my pc, hoping that I could fix it. And for FWs below and at .Net 4.7.2, I got

[Install Block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tC6XE.png)

And that makes sense. Net FW 4.x Runtimes usually include the ones below it. So if I had .Net 4.7.2, then it would include versions 4.0 through 4.7.2. But that was not my case.

[Versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDXt1.png)

*Application for detecting versions: http://www.asoft.be/prod_netver.html*

Notice that I only have FWs 4.6.2 - 4.7.2. It does not look like including all other versions. No wonder the 4.6.1-and-below applications are crashing on me.

Here is an example of a 4.6 FW crashing

[.NET FW 4.6 crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NE3Y.png)

(I already showed you a 4.5 crash). Here is one where the 4.0 crashes

[.NET FW 4.0 crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqhTv.png)

No crashes from 4.6.2-4.7.2.

It seems I don't have .Net FW 4.6 and below, which means that I would have to reinstall them. But I cannot reinstall them, as 4.7.2 is already built-in and thus cannot be removed. 
It is possible for the version detector to have flaws in detecting the lower versions (e.g. *4.5, 4.6*) if the versions exist. Knowing why would shed light on how the other applications can't detect it.

[.NET 4.8 not detected on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1509945/net-4-8-not-detected-on-windows-10) says to do a wipe, but 
I saw this post [Non-technical person facing technical issues with .Net framework](https://superuser.com/questions/1456744/non-technical-person-facing-technical-issues-with-net-framework)
and downloaded from the second link provided in the (unaccepted) answer. Installed it (2015-2019) successfully, but doesn't seem to work as well.

Why would 4.7.2 not include 4.6?

(Note: My actual version is 4.8, but I was able to downgrade to 4.7.2 by uninstalling it.)

(Note: I reinstalled 4.8, and after running the same checking procedure, still the same issue. Stick to 4.7.2 for now.)

(Note: The applications that crash are not my VS projects. They are applications like DropBox, Atom, CMake, etc. which I do not suppose I have permission to modify the code to target .Net 4.8 or 4.7.2 and have the skills to do so.)

---

potentially relevant:

*64-bit OS, x64-based processor*

*Windows 10 Home Single Language, Windows v1803*

*OS build 17134.407*

*Dell*

Comment: 1903 sets the maximum update pause to 35 days now, so I don't think that 365-day pause would be a problem now. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you had it set to a value while on a different version that key is honored. I have documented that exact behavior in my most recent question about a problem I had. I also don’t agree with your statement that the maximum deferred value is 35 on Windows 10 Professional 1903/1909.  This is the first time I noticed you indicated you were using Home not Professional.  I didn’t notice that information when I last commented.

Answer (score 1):

Install a feature update, which can solve the problem. And because moving to 1903 will replace a lot of files, it will fix this issue.

---

**If the PC does not detect the update:** Run the Windows Update Troubleshooter in Troubleshoot Settings to find and fix updating problems. Re-run it if you will retry the troubleshoot.
Then check for updates. (You may wait for an automatic detection otherwise)